# Linux re-install Windows boot partition

Tags: linux, windows-8, partitioning, multi-boot, fedora

I am trying to dual boot Fedora 21 and Windows 8. I have been having large problems, since after the Fedora install I have two EFI partitions, but both contain the /EFI/fedora folder instead of /EFI/Microsoft.

Is there any way to restore a wiped windows boot partition? I have tried re-installing windows off a usb drive but it reports a missing install.wim file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If partition is there and only content is changed then it is recoverable. If partition is deleted then I can't help. If partition is there then you can recover it as:

1. Boot windows from DVD or flash drive make sure you are booting the same window version and same architecture like if installed version is windows 8 64bit then flash or DVD must have the same.
2. Go windows install menu but do not click on install now but click repair computer and then go to Troubleshoot option and advance option and then command prompt.
3. On command prompt type **bootrec.exe /FixMbr** and press enter
   .
4. Then Type **bootrec.exe /FixBoot** and press enter.
5. Exit the command prompt and reboot computer.

If it recovers the windows efi then fine. If not follow the below process:

1. Type diskpart and press enter.
2. Type listdisk and press enter.
3. Type select disk
4. Type list partition and press enter.
5. Type select partition .
6. Type active and press enter.

Close the command prompt and raboot the windows it will bring the winsows up.
If it delete the menu of Linux and do not show Linux menu you can add it from windows using easybcd software(If at all needed).

Comment: Ok that's helpfull. The partition is still there, but the previous win 8 iso I downloaded did not boot. I am currently downloading a different (hopefully better) iso on a new usb

Comment: solved, I booted successfully from a windows usb but encountered a lot of different errors while trying to repair the boot so I ended up just re-installing windows over the old one and now its working great! Thx :D